# Save Selected Sheets to a different work book in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to save a number of worksheets from the current workbook to a different workbook and exclude a sheet named "buttons" (in current one) from that saving process.

Can anybody help please? The number of worksheets is changeable FYI.

Below is what I have so far which include all the sheets from current workbook.

```
Sub SaveAs()

D1 = VBA.Format(Now, "mm_DD_yyyy")
For Each ws In Application.Workbooks
    ws.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\e2309\Desktop\Andy's\GBB_Report_" & D1 & ".csv"
Next ws

Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or more directly

- copy the entire workbook
- delete the redundant sheet

*code*

```
Sub Simpler()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim strFile As String

strFile = "C:\temp\yourfile.xlsm"
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs strFile, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("buttons").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: yes! That's exactly how I figured. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

This might get you a little closer. Note this is not complete and very untested.

```
Sub work()
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim Nwb As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set Nwb = New Workbook
Set WB = ThisWorkbook

For Each WS In WB.Sheets
    If WS.Name <> "Don't copy" Then
        WS.Copy Nwb.Sheets("sheet1")
    End If
Next

Nwb.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Huy, note that you would use your `ws.SaveAs` line where Bigtree has 'nwb.Save'. (be sure to replace your `ws` with his `nwb`)

Comment: what does "sheet1" do there? I don't think i need Nwb, right? 

Error 429: ActiveX component can't create object on "Set Nwb = New Workbook"

Comment: The line ws.copy ws.sheets("sheet1") is wrong. Sorry, I am very new to VBA

Comment: problem solved.
Sub SaveAs()

 D1 = VBA.Format(Now, "mm_DD_yyyy")
For Each ws In Application.Workbooks
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("buttons").delete
ws.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\23225\Desktop\Andy\GVS_Report_" & D1 & ".csv"
Next ws
Application.Quit
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub